# How to save serialized value into a table in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

In my custom model I want to store the data in serialized form. For achieving it by myself I have done the following thing but instead of all this 0 is getting stored against value

In my class Inchoo_Custombuilders_Model_Mysql4_Cableconnector extends Mage_Core_Model_MySql4_Abstract file

```
 $this->_serializableFields = array(
        'cable_id' => array(null, array())
    );
```

I also tried override the _beforeSave Action

```
 protected function _beforeSave()
 {
    if(is_array($this->getValue())){
        var_dump($this->getValue());die();
        $this->setValue(serialize($this->getValue()));
    }
 }
```

And I cannot change the database table design because some functionality that is build on the frontend is running from this table only.

What is the proper way to save serialize data into database in Magento.

Comment: Why is your custom functionality in the Inchoo namespace?

Comment: I have just written Inchoo here on forum..it's just a example..

Comment: what is the fieldtype of the database field?

Comment: field type is "text"

Answer (score 2):

Your methods seem a little bit off.  If that `_beforeSave()` is inside of the `Inchoo_Custombuilders_Model_Mysql4_Cableconnector` class, then it should have an `$object` parameter passed in, and you should be checking `$object->getValue()`, not `$this->getValue()`.

Now, assuming that the field name on the model is `value` (which by the way I would try to avoid that - I think you might run into mysql reserved keyword issues), and assuming that $object->getValue() contains an array, then what you seem to be doing should basically work fine:

```
protected function _beforeSave($object)
{
    if ($object->getValue()) {
        $serializedValue =  serialize($object->getValue());
        $this->setValue($serializedValue);
    }
}
```

If it isn't, then check to see what the value of `$serializedValue` is to make sure that it is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Magento supports serialized configuration items already. You can use the standard Serialized Array class as backend model, you only need to define a frontend class with the required columns.

In my example I'll be creating configurable Document Types.
Configure your item in `config.xml`:

```
<document_types translate="label">
    <label>Document types</label>
    <frontend_model>custombuilders/system_config_form_field_documenttypes</frontend_model>
    <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array</backend_model>
     <sort_order>250</sort_order>
     <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
     <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
     <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</document_types>
```

Create your custom frontend model at `Inchoo/Custombuilders/Block/System/Config/Form/Field/Documenttypes.php`:

```
  <?php
class Inchoo_Custombuilders_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Documenttypes extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Array_Abstract
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addColumn('value', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('inchoo_custombuilders')->__('value'),
            'style' => 'width:250px',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('Label', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('inchoo_custombuilders')->__('Label'),
            'style' => 'width:250px',
        ));
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('inchoo_custombuilders')->__('Add type');
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

And that's it! You can now add custom document types in admin and retrieve them like so:

```
$data = Mage::getStoreConfig('custombuilders/view/document_types');
$data = unserialize($data);
```